# Confusion about the definition of Sobolev spaces on manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, manifolds, sobolev-spaces

Let $(M,g)$ be a manifold with metric $g$ parametrized by the mapping $S$ and parametric domain $\Omega$. The sobolev space of order one with respect to the $L_2(M)$-norm $H^1_2(M)$ is defined as follows: Let $C_2^1 = \{ u \in C^\infty(M) s.t. \forall j = 0,1: \int_M |\nabla^j u |^2 dv(g) < \infty \}$, where $\nabla^0 u = u$ and $\nabla u $ is the ordinary gradient in local coordinates (i.e. in $\Omega$). Note that with above metric, we have $|\nabla u|^2 = (\nabla u)^T g \nabla u$.  The Sobolev space $H^1_2(M)$ is the completion of $C_2^1$ with respect to the norm
\begin{align}
\left \| u \right \|_{H^1_2} = \sum_{j = 0}^1 \left(\int_M | \nabla^j u |^2 dv(g) \right)^{1/2}.
\end{align}

I have a subtle problem with this definition. As an example, suppose that $\Omega = [0,1]$ and
\begin{align}
u(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{ll} 
                           1-2x & \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1/2 \\
                            0    & \quad 1/2 < x \leq 1
\end{array} \right. .
\end{align}
Suppose $M$ is just the line-segment $\Omega$ mapped onto another line in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, I believe, $u \in H_2^1(M)$ should be true.
Now suppose that $[0,1]$ is mapped onto a closed circle (via the mapping $S(x) = (r \cos(2 \pi x),r \sin(2 \pi x)$)), then I feel like $u \notin H_2^1(M)$, this is because on the circle, the function $u$ contains a `jump' at the point where the the boundaries of $\Omega$ connect.

The problem that I am having is that $\left \| u \right \|_{H_2^1} < \infty$ even when $M$ is a circle. The integral is carried out in $\Omega$  and there the discontinuity does not exist.
I believe that the reason that $u$ is not in the sobolev space on the circle must be that it is not contained in the completion of $C_2^1$ in that case. However, I have no idea how to demonstrate that.

More specifically, I'd like to demonstrate that functions that contain discontinuities on $M$, in general, are not contained in $H_2^1(M)$, also when $M$ is an n-dimensional manifold.

Can somebody help me ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: What is a "mapping operator" and a "parametric domain"?

Comment: $s|_\Omega$ gives you $M$. Sorry, I am really not an expert in this field of mathematics.

Comment: No problem, but it will help if you provide some details and/or a reference about what is $s$ and $\Omega$ because the definition of Sobolev spaces on manifolds I'm familiar with doesn't use this kind of terminology at all.

Comment: Also, the point of Sobolev spaces is to allow less regular functions, and in particular, functions with discontinuities so it is unlikely you will be able to show that such functions don't belong to $H_2^1(M)$. There are discontinuous functions that belong to $H_2^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n > 1$ and also to the Sobolev spaces on manifolds using the definitions I'm familiar with.

Comment: @levap: What the OP wanted to say is that $M$ has a global chart $s^{-1} : M \to \Omega$.

Comment: @Yamamoto: In order to be the domain of a parametrization, $\Omega$ must be open; $[0,1]$ is not.

Comment: Well, then the circle doesn't fit into this framework, is it not?

Comment: I understand, the reason why I introduced a parametric domain is because I have a differential equation that is defined on a manifold without boundary. The computations, however, are all carried out in $\Omega$. I would like to demonstrate that the solution of my diff. equ. is an element from $H^1_2(M)$, because then I can impose certain constraints on the solution space in $\Omega$. Here one of them has to be $u(0) = u(1)$ and $u \in H^1_2(\Omega)$, I believe (to make sure that no discontinuities exist on the circle).

Comment: @AlexM. I see your point. It is indeed true that in order for $s^{-1}$ to exist, $\Omega$ must be open. I do, however, need a closed parametric domain. 
In order to repair this, you could require that any function $u(0) = u(1)$ since $s(0) = s(1)$ for the circle. I know this lacks mathematical rigor. I'd just like to be able to translate the continuity properties on $M$ to constraints in $\Omega$.

Comment: @Yamamoto: If you really need it, the only non-empty closed and open subset of $\Bbb R ^n$ is $\Bbb R ^n$ itself, therefore $M$ must be diffeomorphic to it, which significantly restricts your problem.

Comment: I believe it would suffice if somebody could prove that functions that contain discontinuities are not in $H_2^1(M)$. In the case of the circle the conclusion would then have to be that in $\Omega$, $u(0) = u(1)$.